# Can I use this.on to listen to events in EventEmitter? Looking for correct usage of Eventmitter in class in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eventemitter

I am using [EventEmitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) which is an event module in my javascript code. It works just like the `event` module in Node.js. But I am facing problems to use it correctly.

Normally if I use the module in my code, I would create an object of the `EventEmitter` and then use `object.emit` to fire the events and `object.on` to listen to the events. And what I normally do is put `object.on` in another class so it works perfectly.

Now I try to organize my code in ES6 classes. So I extend **EventEmitter** in my customized class. Assume it is called **ClassA**, which is a subclass of **EventEmitter**. If I listen to its own event in the class definition, like this:

```
import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3';

class ClassA extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  method() {
    this.emit('send');
  }

  this.on('send', function(data) {
    // Do something with data
  });
}
```

I am getting an Unexpected token error on `this.on` line. But I am not sure how to listen to the class's own event inside the class or is this even doable? Do I have to put the listeners outside of the class definition?

Comment: Why don't you inject the event emitter instead of inheriting it? Often composition is more flexible and cleaner than inheritance.

Comment: @Yoda you mean create a dedicated event emitter class and use it in this `ClassA`? Suppose I have many objects of `ClassA` and I want the object only listen to its own event, will the listener listen to events from other objects if I use a dedicated event emitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put calls that are supposed to run for each instance inside the constructor:

```
class ClassA extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    …
    this.on('send', data => {
      // Do something with data
    });
  }

  method() {
    this.emit('send');
  }
}
```

Otherwise let the creator of the instances listen to the events, or listen/unlisten from within your class's methods.

Comment: Thanks that looks nice and concise.